# Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to run android -opencv application using eclipse and opencv 3.1

when I try to run the application this error is dispalyed:

> C:\androideclipse\android-ndk-r12b\ndk-build.cmd" 
>   Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
>   jni/Android.mk:9: ../../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
>   make: *** No rule to make target `../../../OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.

I have changed the platform from >properties>android to (android (4.0) API(14) , but the error is still occurring . Thanks very much for any help